# on click add to cart button in woocommerce add 10% extra amount in each product

Tags: woocommerce

**Woocommerce Product Details page:-**

- i want to add  extra price.    when click "add to cart button.
- I want to be able to completely override the product price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calculate_eyehole_fee( $cart_object ) {  
    global $isProcessed;
    if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {

        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            $price = $cart_object->cart_contents[$key]['data']->price;
            $additionCost = $price * 10 / 100;
            $cart_object->cart_contents[$key]['data']->set_price($price + $additionCost);
        } 
        $isProcessed = true;  
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_eyehole_fee', 99 );
```

Comment: it is working fine for static Value. i want to use dynamic price from  product price page.

Comment: What do you mean? This code will add 10% fees to product price!

Comment: i mean 10% coming from product Details page using custom hidden fields

Comment: Then you can get custom field where I have put "* 10" and replace amount by that field value.

Comment: $custom_price = $_POST['extraprice'];$additionCost = $price * $custom_price / 100;

Comment: You can not use $_POST there. You have to add custom data to woocommerce session to do that. And access that woocommmerce updated object.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

Try this code snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate_extra10( $cart_object ) { 
global $isProcessed;

if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {

foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

$price = $cart_object->cart_contents[$key]['data']->price;

$additionCost = $price * 10 / 100;

$cart_object->cart_contents[$key]['data']->set_price($price + `$additionCost);`

} 

$isProcessed = true; 

}
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_extra10', 99 );
```